# Multiple IPs on a Single NIC: UDP Broadcast

Tags: java, windows, networking, udp, broadcast

Problem:
1- Client 1 listens an IP of subnet A.
2- Server sends broadcast message to subnet B.
3- Client 1 also read this message through its IP which is in subnet A.
- No such situation if a message is not broadcast but unicast.

I am trying to write a Java application that listens some IPs and ports which are defined on single network interface. Below you can find an example of my network configuration:

`netsh interface ip>show address`

Configuration for interface "Local Area Connection"
    DHCP enabled:                         No
    IP Address:                           22.108.131.1
    SubnetMask:                           255.255.255.0
    IP Address:                           22.108.132.1
    SubnetMask:                           255.255.255.0
    IP Address:                           22.108.133.1
    SubnetMask:                           255.255.255.0
    InterfaceMetric:                      0

I am opening datagram channels and binding them to these IP addresses. For each IP I have different thread to respond messages that is coming from the channel.

Now the thing is, a server sends UDP broadcast messages to

> 22.108.131.255
>   22.108.132.255
>   and so on.

However in the thread which is created to listen 22.108.131.1 for example, I am receiving the broadcast message which is destined to 22.108.132.255. I check incoming messages using Wireshark and it tells me that the messages come correctly as 22.108.132.255 however in my application I see that the endpoint of the message is 22.108.131.1 that is the listening thread.

At first I thought my implementation was wrong but more surprising issue is incoming non-broadcast messages. I mean, if the destination of the message is 22.108.131.1 then 22.108.132.1 does not receive that, which is obviously how it should be. But what I do not understand is when it is about broadcast message why wouldn't it run like it should.

I am not sure whether the problem is caused by windows multiple IP configuration or not. But what I am observing is the operating system delivers subnet-A's broadcast message to subnet-B.

Another thing that might be clue is this, I only talked about 22.108.131.1 and 22.108.132.1 above, although I defined 22.108.133.1 as well. If I do not open a datagram channel for that IP, I can still read the broadcast message of that subnet from other IPs.

So am I missing something here? Or is it the nature of network handling of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

an IP ending in 255 is a broadcast message which will be heard by every node in the network.

Comment: I believe OP knows that - just take a look at the title and contents. He's concern is about received endpoint address.

Comment: Bob, welcome to stack. It's nice to help people. I love it. But sometimes I find myself answering a small part of a person's question. In these cases, I ask myself if I have helped to resolve a problem or just thrown some facts their way. I hope you continue to contribute, but in this case I ask, have you helped Hakan with his question? Is he likely to resolve his dilemma now? Is there any analysis you could add that could be further help?

Comment: Actually, that's not correct. I know that it is a broadcast message and I think I clearly stated that in my post. However, broadcast message's delivery address changes depending on the configuration, sub-net mask for example.